# Editing Images With PHPickerViewController SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want my user to be able to edit his image right after he picks it with the new `PHPickerViewController`, I was able to do it with `UIImagePickercontroller` like so:

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var image: UIImage?

    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIImagePickerController
    var sourceType : UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        let parent: ImagePicker

        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
            if let uiImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.image = uiImage
            } else {
                print("no image!")
            }

            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = sourceType
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {

    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }


}
```

But, when updating to `Xcode 12.0` I need to support the `iOS 14.0` users by implanting the `PHPickerViewController` like so:

```
@available(iOS 14, *)
struct PHPicker : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return PHPicker.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }
    
    @Binding var image : UIImage?
    @Binding var picker : Bool
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PHPickerViewController {
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
        config.filter = .images
        config.selectionLimit = 1
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiView: PHPickerViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            for img in results {
                if img.itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self){
                    img.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (image, err) in
                        guard let image = image as? UIImage else {return}
                        self.parent.image = image
                        self.parent.picker = false
                    }
                } else {
                    print("error getting image")
                }
            }
        }
        
        var parent : PHPicker
        
        init(parent1: PHPicker) {
            parent = parent1
        }
    }
}
```

How to I enable the user to edit his image (cutting, changing size, and so on...)?

Comment: I think that the new PHPickerViewController did not support editing at all for now.

Comment: Is this still unavailable in PHPicker? Did you end up finding a solution? Thanks!

Comment: @phiredrop did you found a solution?

Comment: As far as I understand, this capability still does not exist for PHPickerViewController